# How to generate signed AWS S3 URL having only 3 parameters access key, signature, expires using php?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

After uploading a file on S3, i have bucket name and path of the file. Now, i want to generate signed url for that file using PHP. I am able to generate signed url using AWS PHP SDK 3.

**Sample Url :**

```
https://xyz.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pathoffile?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=<CREDS>&X-Amz-Expires=18000&X-Amz-Signature=<SIGNATURE>
```

But i want to generate simple signed URL. Eg:

```
https://xyz.s3.amazonaws.com/pathoffile?AWSAccessKeyId=<CREDS>&Expires=1628581719&Signature=<SIGNATURE>
```

Can anyone help me with PHP Code in generating this type of AWS signed URL. Also, do we need AWS SDK for this ?

Comment: I believe you want to set the [signature version to v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_configuration.html#signature-version).  You can use the AWS SDK to do this, or [create the signature following AWS's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html).

Comment: Is the signed URL V2 no longer supported ?

Comment: Support for [SigV2 is being phased out](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-sigv2-deprecation-period-extended-modified/)